# Checking the legality of parentheses in regular expression with LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I need some help,

I have a problem with checking the legality of parentheses in a regular expression,

while the input is math exp, and the output is a boolean value if the term is legal or not.

I will be happy for an answer or instruction...

Thanks.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65706671/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by legality? can you show some example expression which is legal and illegal?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about implementing the parenthesis matching algorithm? Something like this:

https://www.algorithmsandme.com/matching-parenthesis-problem/

Traditional text based approaches use a stack. You can likely implement something similar using a Queue in LV and use Enqueue at front for the push method of a stack.

EDIT:

[image]

[image]